# miktex-texworks.exe does not start

Tags: miktex, texworks

I dont know the exact reason why, but 2 days ago texworks in my pc (windows 8) stopped working.  Everytime I wish to start the program I receive the following message:

[image]

Comment: Probably you updated/installed only a part of the packages. Start the package manager (admin), synchronize and check for uninstalled miktex-packages. Before you install anything see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I chose an easy way to solve the problem. I uninstalled texworks as well as MiKTex and installed them again. Now, it works.